# How can I make a File Attachment control conditionally required?

Tags: microsoft-infopath

How can I make a `File Attachment` control conditionally required?  For other controls, such as a text box I can add a data validation rule that `and`'s the condition (a checkbox being checked) and the control's `isBlank`.  However, `File Attachment` controls lack this function (data validation), so how can I emulate it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the box Cannot be blank in the properties window?

Right click on the control, properties, Cannot be blank.

Comment: That's not conditional at all though...

Comment: At least in InfoPath 2007, the "cannot be blank" field is disabled for file attachment fields (and disabled in the "on" position).